# UISegmentControl custom images not proper

Tags: uisegmentedcontrol

I have a segment control with 5 segments. I need custom images to be shown on each segment for selected and deselected each.

[image]

**Problem**

The problem is when I place image programmatically on selection of segment I get default blue color on the left side of the segments

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810493/uisegmentedcontrol-image-highlighting-bug-in-ios6

Comment: @verbumdei : can you add your comment as answer, I will accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug found in iOS6 at the moment. The solution is to change the *segmentedControlStyle* of the UISegmentedControl to **UISegmentedControlStyleBar** and set the *momentary* property to **YES**.

[UISegmentedControl image highlighting bug in iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810493/uisegmentedcontrol-image-highlighting-bug-in-ios6)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a workaround. I changed the UISegmentControl style to **Bar** and set state **Momentary to YES** which removed the default blue color on selection. I guess this is a bug in iOS6. Found the solution from another stack overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810493/uisegmentedcontrol-image-highlighting-bug-in-ios6). Thanks to verbumdei